# Command Line Tool interact with Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, command-line, appkit, foundation

I have a Cocoa Document-Based Application (text editor) and I want to be able to interact with it from the command line.

For example, I'd like to set it as the editor for typing git/svn commit messages on the command line.

Assuming I create a Command Line Tool using Foundation, what is the best way for my command line tool to communicate with the GUI application?

Obviously I can use standard open events to have my app open a specific file, but I also need the command line app to wait until the GUI app has finished with the document (user closes the editor window) before exiting (similar to `mate -w file.txt` in TextMate's command line tool, or the equivalent in various other mac text editors).

TextMate 2 [uses a socket file](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Applications/mate/src/mate.cc). Is this the best approach? If possible I'd like to use something higher level, perhaps `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`.

Comment: can you use a named pipe? or a socket/port?

Comment: @Shark TextMate 2 uses a socket, but it seems like a lot of fairly complex code, so I'm treating it as a last resort. I'm not sure about a named pipe... how do I do that? Would that work if the GUI application is already running when the command line tool is executed? If I have problems with NSDistributedNotificationCenter I'll look into it, unless you want to post an answer explaining how it works.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe also, don't be scared of Sockets, there's tons of sample code online.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDistributedNotificationCenter` would likely work fine, if that is the abstraction level you prefer. Its interfaces are similar to `NSNotificationCenter`. Regarding `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`:

- it is limited to plist types
- dropping notifications are permitted
- it is 'expensive'
- the latency may be unpredictable
- Sandboxed apps cannot use the `userInfo:` parameter

You may find sockets preferable if you want to transfer a lot of information, or if you want something more robust/predictable.

Comment: Performance is a non-issue, I'm probably only sending 5 or 10 notifications per day under typical use. Does anyone know how frequently notifications are dropped? And what is the worst case for the "unpredictable" latency? Those could be deal breakers, but maybe they only occur if you spam the system with thousands of messages? I only need to send one message, and very infrequently. Perhaps the GUI app can wait for the command line to send a confirmation notification, and present an error to the user after waiting 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert re frequency: not really answerable because notifications are dropped when the message queue fills up, so... it ultimately depends on a number of things which are not consistent across users. 10 per day should be no issue. if it is, you can step into the abstraction layer `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` uses, and use `NSConection`+`NSDistantObject` directly. That, or you could use `NSMachPort`. latency is unpredictable because it will depend on how fast listeners respond to enqueued notifications, which may be added to your run loop. (cont)

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I actually used `NSDistributedNotifcationCenter` for some high density messaging in the OS X.4 era (high density: during stress testing). Basically, there was a system where I had system plugins and an app which would present statuses of system-wide tasks (active task count, result messages). The workload tested was up to a few hundred active, continuous tasks per second. I don't remember issues regarding dropped messages in that scenario. However, that all goes through a global message queue so it's not worth a whole lot because another user's system may vary greatly :)

Comment: @AbhiBeckert So I guess my short conclusion would be to just start with `NSDistributedNotifcationCenter` and if you ever notice an issue, switch to a lower level abstraction. Just abstract how your app communicates from the rest of your program, and switching to a lower level abstraction should be easy -- if it is necessary (quite unlikely, i'd say).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the iTerm source code here:

svn co https://iterm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/iterm iterm

You can see how they did it. They used Growl notifications. Growl is a comprehensive notification framework that will allow you to really control what is happening and respond to everything correctly. You can find more information on Growl here:

http://growl.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can add URL scheme to your app in project info pane.

When anybody anywhere will try to go to url `yourscheme://info/for/your/app` it will launch your app if it wasn't launched and will pass the arguments.

Here is the code in your app to process the url

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

// ...

    [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager] setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleAppleEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                                                     forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}

- (void)handleAppleEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *urlString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
// .. process your url
}
```

Comment: Can a command line tool also register it's own URL scheme? I need communication in both directions between the command line tool and the GUI app.

Comment: i don't think you can do communication between command line tool and GUI app. You can try making your app "Background only" by setting "Application is background only" to Yes in info.plist. In this case the app will support URL schemes and NSDistributedNotificationCenter

Comment: The whole point of my task is to allow UNIX shell commands, such as `git` to interact with a GUI text editor. It can definitely be done, most mac text editors do it.

Comment: You can use FSEvents to track folder change, and put files there, but i don't think it is a best solution.

Comment: Yeah, I've worked with FSEvents in the past. I want the GUI app to notify the command line app when the text editor window has been closed. There's no FSEvent for that.

Comment: Are you sure you need a command line tool? you can launch any app from command line, so there will be no difference between command line tool and background app.

Comment: Yes, I need the command line tool. I want the GUI app to send messages to the command line tool.